# java multithread programming memory consistency problem

Tags: java, multithreading

A is a subclass of AbstractCollection.

```
final A a = new A();
... //Add some objects into a

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future f1 = es.submit(new Callable<B>() {
    public B call() {
        ... //Modify the objects in a
        return B;
    }
});
f1.get();
... //Read a
```

Now the problem is that when I read a, the modification is not there. According to java documentation: "actions taken by the asynchronous computation happen-before actions following the corresponding Future.get() in another thread". So I'm wondering why this inconsistency would happen. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is basic concurrency. Perhaps you should take some time to read the [Lesson: Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: I just found out what could be happening. I was inspecting variable "a" using debug in Eclipse IDE, in which "a" was found to be not modified. However, when I print out the values of "a" without using debug, the modification can be seen. Perhaps I shouldn't use debug for multithreading programming?

Comment: the debugger can sometimes have display issues with variable values etc, best to put extensive logging in your code and look at the output.

Answer (score 2):

I re-wrote your example with some standard objects and it seems to work fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    final StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
    a.append("a");

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Future<String> f1 = es.submit(new Callable<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public String call()
        {
            a.append("b");
            return "done";
        }
    });

    f1.get();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    es.shutdownNow();
}
```

If you are using a good [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you can always breakpoint the code to see the concurrency behaviour in action.

Perhaps your problem is within your `A` class.

Comment: also, you can log the thread name via Thread.currentThread().getName()